# Looking for an open-source decompiler for ARM (file format elf32-littlearm)

Tags: arm, decompiling

I am looking for an open-source decompiler for ARM (file format elf32-littlearm).I tried using Retargetable decompiler, it works great. The reason I am looking for open-source is that I want to understand the overall concept, especially how the memory addresses referred in instructions(LDR/STR only, in arm) are resolved to specific symbols?

Comment: you have tried disassembling yes?

Comment: Yes. From assembly, decompiler like the one mentioned above maps load stores to specific high-level variables in C. I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: as the decompiling description shows that is not always possible, but the disassembly is about as good as you are going to get, compile for debug and more labels should be in there.  only some of the time is there a direct load and store related to a variable anyway, can you provide a small program sample that you want to see what is created from it?